# angularjs bootstrap - set title if

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have a **<tr>** that I want to give it **title**

```
<tr title="qualified">
```

if a controller variable **qualified** is true

I am using AngularJS.

Comment: Can you share your full  html and controller ?

Comment: @ThanhTùng using ng-if won't show the th if the value is false, I want to show it in all cases. I added solution, check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it this way:

```
<tr title="{{ qualified ? 'Qualified' : ''}}">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<tr title="{{ qualified ? 'title' : '' }}">
```